# Doing a MERGE without replacing null values in Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, merge

I need to make an upsert to a table.

Using Oracle.

1. I created a temporary table that has the same columns as the original.
2. I want to merge the temp one into the original but without replacing null values from the temp table, i.e:

table1:

```
Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Salary
123, Bob, Foo, 100
```

table2:

```
Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Salary
123, NULL, NULL, 200
```

After merge:

table1:

```
Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Salary
123, Bob, Foo, 200
```

I tried constructing this:

```
MERGE INTO t1 wu USING t2 tmp ON (wu.Id = tmp.Id) WHEN MATCHED THEN
CASE WHEN tmp.First_Name IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE SET wu.First_Name = tmp.First_Name 
ELSE
UPDATE SET wu.First_Name = wu.First_Name
END
CASE WHEN tmp.Last_Name IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE SET wu.Last_Name = tmp.Last_Name 
ELSE
UPDATE SET wu.Last_Name = wu.Last_Name 
END
CASE WHEN tmp.Salary IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE SET wu.Salary = tmp.Salary 
ELSE
UPDATE SET wu.Salary = wu.Salary 
END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES(tmp.Id, tmp.First_Name, LastName, tmp.Salary);
```

But I get:

```
ORA-00927: missing equal sign
```

I do not want to use PL/SQL - all from c# directly.

Comment: The [MERGE statement's syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) is very strict. `WHEN MATCHED THEN` can only have an `UPDATE` clause and an optional `DELETE` clause. Within the UPDATE's `SET` clause, you can do your `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @madreflection Can you give an example based on the code I wrote?

Comment: Nope. @Littlefoot has provided a much better answer than I could have. I was going to suggest `COALESCE`, as it were.  `NVL` is probably more idiomatic for Oracle, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NVL` might help.

Test case:

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number, first_name varchar2(10),
  2    last_name varchar2(10), salary number);

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 (id number, first_name varchar2(10),
  2    last_name varchar2(10), salary number);

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into t1 values (123, 'Bob', 'Foo', 100)
  3    into t2 values (123, null, null, 200)
  4    into t2 values (555, 'Little', 'Foot', 20)
  5  select * From dual;

3 rows created.
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into t1 using t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
  2  when matched then update set
  3    t1.first_name = nvl(t2.first_name, t1.first_name),
  4    t1.last_name  = nvl(t2.last_name , t1.last_name),
  5    t1.salary     = nvl(t2.salary    , t1.salary)
  6  when not matched then insert
  7    values (t2.id, t2.first_name, t2.last_name, t2.salary);

2 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from t1 order by id;

        ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME      SALARY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       123 Bob        Foo               200
       555 Little     Foot               20

SQL>
```